# my understanding on this Perldata example

Tags: perl

Perldata gives the following example.

```
$field = $query->radio_group(
  name => 'group_name',
  values => ['eenie','meenie','minie'],
  default => 'meenie',
  linebreak => 'true',
  labels => \%labels
);
```

My understanding for this example is that , “radio-group” is used as a key for hash “query”. This key, “radio-group” , itself is a hashref, including  name=’group_name’,etc.  Moreover,     this hashref, identified by “radio_group” is assigned to $field. If my understanding is wrong, please correct me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$query->radio_group` is a *method call*.

In this particular example the method is being *called* on the *object instance* `$query` with the hash containing the given key-value pairs.

It's the same as if the following had been written:

```
my %tmp = (
    name => 'group_name',
    values => ['eenie','meenie','minie'],
    default => 'meenie',
    linebreak => 'true',
    labels => \%labels
);

$field = $query->radio_group(%tmp);
```

which should make it clear that the hashed set of *parameters* is *independent* of `$query` itself.

The *result* of that method call is then assigned to `$field`.

Answer (score 4):

This is a call on the method "radio_group" from the object $query. There are no hashes there, just a bunch of parameter pairs separated by commas and fat commas (=>).  From perlop:

> The => operator is a synonym for the comma except that it causes its
>   left operand to be interpreted as a string if it begins with a letter
>   or underscore and is composed only of letters, digits and underscores.
>   This includes operands that might otherwise be interpreted as
>   operators, constants, single number v-strings or function calls. If in
>   doubt about this behavior, the left operand can be quoted explicitly.
>   Otherwise, the => operator behaves exactly as the comma operator or
>   list argument separator, according to context.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to writing:

```
my %params = (
  name => 'group_name',
  values => ['eenie','meenie','minie'],
  default => 'meenie',
  linebreak => 'true',
  labels => \%labels
);

$field = radio_group( $query, %params );
```

So `radio_group` is not a hash key at all, but a subroutine/method/function.

The tell-tale signs are:

- The absence of `[]` and `{}`, used to denote array indices and hash keys
- The presence of `()` parens after `radio_group`

Comment: "The hash here" is not correct, as there are NO hashes in the code (apart from %labels)...

Comment: @tadmc : It's so easy to forget about lists :|

Comment: Yes, and list confusion is exactly what led this poster off into the woods. He saw a "hash shaped list" and started thinking "hash" when there was no hash there.  :-)

Comment: That code is not equivalent. It assumes `radio_group` exists in the current namespace and it skips method dispatch.